# Performance comparison for SELECT and UPDATE when update a table partially

Tags: mysql, performance, select, sql-update

There's a table need to be update. However, the amount of data changed (comparing the fresh data we got and those in database) is unknown.

I can think of two ways to implement this.

1. Select all data and compare them in web server. Then only update
   those changed.
2. Simply update all data.

I guess there's an performance borderline for them. If the effected rows is, let's say, less than 1,000, then maybe method 2 is better.

My question is:

1. Is there a general criteria for this?
2. Can select compare with update operations generally?

Suppose the database is MySQL, if needed.

Comment: This is called micro-optimization. You should only think about that kind of optimization after you run into troubles with the normal way (using updates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are replacing the entire table (possibly with mostly the same data), it is fairly straight forward to do it this way, and not worry about which approach:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
Load the new data entirely into `new`
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;  -- atomic and instantaneous (no downtime)
DROP TABLE old;
```

If only part of the rows are available, load them into a temp table, then do a multi-table `UPDATE` to transfer any new values into the real table.

If your new data might have new rows, then you need another step to locate the new rows and `INSERT ... SELECT LEFT JOIN ...` them into the real table.

Please provide more details if you need further discussion.